# Redirect 301 special character

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've this url from my website :

```
/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/logo.jpg%3F46189a
```

I want to redirect this url to :

```
/my-work/
```

So in my `.htaccess` file I wrote this :

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /wp-content/uploads/2013/10/logo.jpg%3F46189a /my-work/
```

But it does not work.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `RewriteRule` instead of `Redirect` directive and also make sure this is your first rule below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/uploads/2013/10/logo\.jpg\x3F46189a /my-work/? [L,R=301,NC]
```